How to set different logo sizes in GitHub README and pkgdown homepage?
I'm developing an R package and using pkgdown for the website. I want the package logo to appear smaller in the GitHub README but larger on the homepage of the website, similar to the data.table package (GitHub, website).
I tried different CSS approaches but couldn't get it to work. What is the best way to achieve this?





https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/315ab544d33a88b916fa5316be5ff5964c3e7e1c/README.md#L2 (The secret here is, simply, that GitHub ignores most HTML attributes when rendering markdown.)

@KonradRudolph Thanks for the hint, but could you please share the entire solution as it is not obvious to me what I should do? Thanks!

Apologies, I just noticed that GitHub borked the link. The correct link is this: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/315ab544d33a88b916fa5316be5ff5964c3e7e1c/README.md?plain=1#L2 (i.e. the source code)

In pkgdown you can specify a different index.md file to make the home page instead of the README.md file that github displays. The instructions in these docs worked for me and now I have a readme for the repo the R package is in then an index.Rmd and index.md in a folder called pkgdown with different widths in markdown like below.
whatever markdown stuff
# some header <img src="man/figures/logo.png" width = 200 alt="logo" align="right"/>
other markdown stuff


You can do this, but ‘data.table’ doesn’t — and it doesn’t seem necessary for OP.

I know that you wrote that you had tried CSS, but this must work if you have custom CSS for the rmarkdown doc:
.main img {
    max-width: 36%; #ajust for your please
    height: auto; 
}

